# React : Storing child components in parent constructor as this.child - Is this a bad idea?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to store my child components in the parent constructor as attributes of the class instance. On the state change, I am expecting the parent (hence the child) to rerender and for the letter "b" to be on the screen verses "a". Why does this not work?

**Does not show "b" on state change**

```
class Parent extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
         this.state = {letter : "a"};
         setTimeout(() => this.setState({letter: "b"}, 1000);
    }
         this.child= <Child letter = this.state.letter>
     }
     render() {
      return this.child;
     }
}

class Child extends React.Component {
    render() {
    <p>{this.prop.letter}</p>
}
}
```

But when I do not store the child component as a class attribute of the parent, but instead render it directly in the render method, it works. The child component reflects the change. Is this because render creates a new JSX object every time it is run, and by storing the child jsx as a attribute of the parent object, I am essentially rendering that old child object?

**Correctly Shows "b" on state change**

````
class Parent extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
         this.state = {letter : "a"};
         setTimeout(() => this.setState({letter: "b"}, 1000);
    }
     }
     render() {
      return <Child letter = {this.state.letter}/>;
     }
}

class Child extends React.Component {
    render() {
    <p>{this.prop.letter}</p>
}
}```
````

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't return an object as `render return` statement, it should be most of the time a `jsx` so if you want to do your wrong way, you need something like this:

```
render() {
  return <div>{this.child}</div>
}
```

But let's see why that's wrong, in `React` change in `state or props` will result in a rerender, and that's why you need to keep data in those places, otherwise like your case (if you change it like I showed above which is wrong), you get `stale data` and as you said the `letter` you're getting in the `Child` Component is old version and will not be updated

so let's say it in another way, the `constructor` function will only be called at the initialization and in that moment you set `this.child attribute` with the letter `a`, after `1000ms` the state will change to letter `b` but you're `constructor` function will not be called again. so you still have the old value.

in the mean time because the `state` has changed from `a` to `b` `render` function will be invoked again, and here if you had the `Child` component in the `render function` as a `jsx` you get new data